# Port 445 blocks administrative functions (Active Directory)

Tags: windows, smb

For security reasons, I want to block 445 in my AD (Active Directory) environment. One of them is to disable access to SMB shared folders.

But my problem is if I block all inbound TCP connections to a workstation from this port, then I cannot connect to the workstation via rsop.msc (to receive all applied GPOs). Does someone know a best practice to solve this problem?

I tried to find out which service is blocking this action, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'll check when I have the ability, but most likely it is the Remote Registry RPC service – and possibly one other RPC service – which the rsop.msc tool wants to access using the Named Pipe transport, and this transport goes over SMB.

An easy way to find out is to fire up Wireshark and look at what pipe the tool is opening and what RPC service it's requesting over it.

Some MS-RPC tools access services over TCP (in which case they need port 135 "portmapper"), some run over Named Pipes (in which case they need port 445), some run over both but will result in long delays if the "preferred" transport is blocked by firewall.

Don't just block port 445 outright – instead *limit* who can access it (i.e. list specific IP address prefixes in the "Scope" tab). So if you need SMB for administration over MS-RPC, but want to prevent shared folders, then just limit the allowed remote hosts to your "IT team" subnet only (or the closest equivalent) and disallow everything else.